# WP Вызов метода класса из функции

Tags: php, wordpress, классы, static

Имеется вот такой тестовый код на `php` для выполнения на странице WordPress подключен к хуку `init` на `page.php`

```
class MyClass {
    public function aaa () {
        echo "It's function aaa";
    }

static public function bbb () {
        echo "It's function bbb";
    }
}

add_action('init',   MyClas::aaa()  )
```

Вопрос, как добиться выполнения значений функций `aaa()`, `bbb()` на данной странице ?  Я читал про [статическое связывание](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) но что-то не могу разобраться, как оно применяется. Объясните, пожалуйста кто в теме.

Comment: Ваш метод `aaa()` не есть статическим, так-то и не понятно к чему вообще там статическое связывание.

Comment: Да, вот только это не выводит результаты работы функции... ни aaa() ни bbb()

Comment: В случае с статическим методом должно быть `add_action('init', 'MyClass::bbb');`. в случае с не статическим, нужно сначала создать объект класса и потом можно сделать `add_action('init', ['MyClass', 'aaa']);`. Но лучше опишите какую проблему Вы пытаетесь решить таким образом, возможно что это Вам и вовсе не нужно.

Comment: Написание класса, просто ради того чтобы это был класс, как такового смысла иметь не будет.

Comment: это был тестовый вопрос на собеседовании. Который благополучно провалил.  Не ищите смысла))) Ищу ответ на то, как на него надо было ответить, если вдруг ещё раз попадется. Почему-то вызовы `add_action('init', 'MyClass::bbb'); add_action('init', ['MyClass', 'init']);` не отображают результаты выполнений функции на странице. Валидный ли тут хук `init` ?

Comment: Валидный, даже перепроверил на тестовом ВП, у меня работают оба. В случае с не статическим методом, не забудьте создать объект `$my_class = new MyClass(); add_action('init', [$my_class, 'aaa']);`. Нуу, провалить один или даже несколько вопросов не так страшно)